# Could not create a RabbitMQ static shovel in the config file

Tags: configuration, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I failed to convert a dynamic shovel to a static one in the RabbitMQ config file.

I followed the example from the official guide at https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel-static.html. I changed my `advanced.config` file at Windows default's path `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ` like the one is shown below.

But either I get a syntax error or the shovel does not properly run.

My dynamic shovel looks like this.

[image]

and my attempt to convert it into static is this.

```
{rabbitmq_shovel,
  [ {shovels, [ 
  
  

            {from_local_to_cloud, [  
               {source, [
                 {protocol, amqp091},
                 {uris, ["amqp://"]},                    
                 {declarations, [
                                    
                 ]},
                 {queue, <<"local_to_cloud">>}
                ]},

            
               {destination, [
                 {protocol, amqp091},
                 {uris, ["amqp://dzjkevdt:<password>@sparrow.rmq.cloudamqp.com/dzjkevdt"]},                  
                 {declarations, [
                        
                 ]},
                 {queue, <<"local_to_cloud">>}
                ]}      
                
            ]
        }             
                  
                  
                  
     ]}
  ]},
```

Running the above configuration I get `state terminated`.

[image]

So, how do I create the static shovel like the dynamic I created in the attached image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question.

I had to manually create the queue first. I thought it would be created automatically but this was not true.

The `advanced.config` for shovel's plugin looks like this.

```
    {from_local_to_cloud, 
        [  
           {source, [
             {protocol, amqp091},
             {uris, ["amqp://"]},                    
             {declarations, []},
             {queue, <<"local_to_cloud">>}                 
            ]},

        
           {destination, [
             {protocol, amqp091},
             {uris, ["amqp://dzjkevdt:<password>@sparrow.rmq.cloudamqp.com/dzjkevdt"]},                  
             {declarations, []},
             {queue, <<"local_to_cloud">>}
            ]}
            
        ]
    }
```